# Why python subprocess stops executing when it runs a certain command?

Tags: python, automation, subprocess, break, pipenv

I want to automate certain tasks during development. This is a part of one of those tasks. I'm trying to install django automatically with pipenv.

```
import os
import subprocess 

def run(project):
    os.mkdir(project)
    os.chdir(project)
    subprocess.run("pipenv install django".split())
    os.mkdir("io")
    os.chdir("io")
    subprocess.run("pipenv shell".split())
    subprocess.run("django-admin startproject _django".split())
    print(f"Created new django project at {project}/io/_django")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    run("hello-world")
```

When i run this code it execute up to the line:

```
subprocess.run("pipenv shell".split())
```

but doesn't run the following lines.
Why is that? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `pipenv shell` spawns an interactive shell and it expects input on stdin.

You’d be better using `pipenv run` to run commands in your virtual environment: `pipenv run django-admin ...`

P.S.: you can remove `.split()`, `subprocess.run` can work with command in form of the string. Use explicit array of arguments in case you need to be able to include space as a character inside of an argument, or when working with untrusted (user-supplied) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The final curated code:
(Credits to @Andrew Morozko)

```
import os
import subprocess 

def run(project):
    os.mkdir(project)
    os.chdir(project)
    subprocess.run("pipenv install django")
    os.mkdir("io")
    os.chdir("io")
    subprocess.run("pipenv run django-admin startproject _django")
    print(f"Created new django project at {project}/io/_django")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    run("hello-world")
```